# in R is there a simple way to name a single list element using a function

Tags: r

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
a <- list("1" = 10, as.character(2) = 20)
```

What I'm expecting is for `as.character(2)` to return "2" and for `a` to subsequently return:

```
> a
$`1`
[1] 10

$`2`
[1] 20
```

Instead I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "a <- list("1" = 1, as.character(2)[1] ="
```

Is there a way to do this on one line without having to revert down the `names(a) <- *namesVector*` route?

Comment: just run `(a <- setNames(list(10,20),c(1,2)))` or even `\`names<-\`(list(10,20),c(1,2))`

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks!!!!!! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If we want to do the `as.character`, it can be done with `dplyr::lst`  by evaluating (`!!`) the string while doing an assignment (`:=`)

```
dplyr::lst("1" = 10, !!as.character(2) := 20)
#$`1`
#[1] 10

#$`2`
#[1] 20
```